# jQuery datepicker on click of icon

Tags: jquery, html, date, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to show the jQuery datepicker on click of a FontAwesome icon which is inside the input field. Below is the code:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
  <label for="datepicker">Date of birth*</label>
  <input type="text" name='datepicker' class="form-control"  value="Select date" id="datepicker" ng-required="true" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" >
  <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
</div>
```

```js
jQuery('.fa-calendar').on('click' , function() {
  jQuery(this).datepicker().trigger('focus');
});
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker();
  $('.fa-calendar').click(function() {
    $("#datepicker").focus();
  });
});
```

- Initialise datepicker once only

Here is the example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker();
  $('.fa-calendar').click(function() {
    $("#datepicker").focus();
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
  <label for="datepicker">Date of birth*</label>
  <input type="text" name='datepicker' class="form-control"  value="Select date" id="datepicker" ng-required="true" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" >
  <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: How would go about doing this globally for all datepickers? I wonder would it be a good idea to shim the datepicker for this purpose?

Comment: Brilliant ... due to my jQuery version, I had to code ".trigger('focus')" rather than just ".focus()", but anyway "focus" did the trick for me ... all of the other solutions which I encountered in various SO posts did NOT work for me!

Answer (score 5):

```
 <script>
   $(document).on('click',".calendar",function(){
         $("#datepicker").datepicker("show");
     });    
 </script>
```

Comment: Please don't submit a block of code without any explanation why and how that solves the problem.

Comment: This worked for me BUT it had the nasty side effect that my date popup disappeared a fraction of a second after it appeared (I realize now that this was probably due to the "click" event cascading through to the parent element, so "event.stopPropagation()" would probably have fixed that)

Answer (score 1):

```js
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      showOn: "button",
      buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      buttonText: "icono",
showOn: "both"
    });
  } );
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Icon trigger</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to trigger the datepicker on the input box, not the icon, so you need to change

```
jQuery(this).datepicker().trigger('focus');`
```

to be

```
jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker().trigger('focus');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `'open'` setting on a datepicker to programmatically open it. There's no need to trigger a `focus` event. You also need to call the `datepicker()` method on the `#datepicker` element, not the clicked icon. Try this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker();

  $('.fa-calendar').on('click', function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker('open');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
<label for="datepicker">Date of birth*</label>
<input type="text" name='datepicker' class="form-control"  value="Select 
 date" id="datepicker_val" ng-required="true" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" >
        <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
</div>
```

JS

```
jQuery(".fa-calendar").datepicker();
```

This is what you want to do. It will work, you can fill date in your input type like below.

```
jQuery(".fa-calendar").datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev){

            jQuery("#datepicker_val").val(ev.date.valueOf());

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('.fa-calendar').on('click' , function() { 
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#startdate').click(); 
});
```

Hope This will work...!!