# JQuery datepicker on click on label

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I want a JQuery datepicker to show when I click on a specific label. I have a HTML like this:

```
<label id="kezd_datum_label">Data</label><input style="display:none;" id="kezd_datum" />
```

And some following JQueries like these:

```
$( function() {
   $( "#kezd_datum" ).datepicker({
         dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd"        
   });
} );

 $("#kezd_datum_label").click(function() {
     $("#kezd_datum").datepicker("show");
 });
```

And

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $( "#kezd_datum" ).datepicker({
         dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd"        
     });

 $("#kezd_datum_label").click(function() {
     $("#kezd_datum").focus();
 });           
});
```

I tried to copy the codes from here [jQuery datepicker on click of icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43605222/jquery-datepicker-on-click-of-icon), and it was accepted and everyone says it works, but it does not for some reason. However, if I make input visible, the datepicker appears as it should. Just not if I click on that label.

If a put in a `window.alert("something");` into any of the click functions, they also run and appear.

Comment: you are missing execute function. Should be `.focus()` instead of `.focus`

Comment: Yeah, fixed. But still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace `display: none` to `opacity: 0;width: 0` to show the input and use `for` to point to your input.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#kezd_datum").datepicker();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<label for="kezd_datum" id="kezd_datum_label">Data</label><input style="opacity: 0; width: 0" id="kezd_datum" />
```

Comment: Works, thank you, can't accept because spam protection. Any reason why label needs it, but a button does not?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just want to clarify why your previous code was not working and how to make it work.

You're doing `$("#kezd_datum").focus();` while you `div` is hidden. So you can't focus on a hidden element. And showing `datapicker` for that element again. As a result you got nothing.

You just need to show it first and then show the `datapicker` and this would work

Cheers!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     $( "#kezd_datum" ).datepicker({
         dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd"        
     });
          
});


$( function() {  
   $( "#kezd_datum" ).datepicker({
         dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd"        
   });
} );

 $("#kezd_datum_label").click(function() {
    $("#kezd_datum").show().focus();
    setTimeout(()=>{
    $("#kezd_datum").datepicker("show");
    },20)
     
     
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.min.css" />
<label id="kezd_datum_label">Data</label><input style="display:none;" id="kezd_datum" />
```